# Solr - Multiple Collections with facets

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

This is a question related to Solr (8.8.x) with 2 types of data on a distributed environment. One type that rarely changes. Another type that is frequently changes.
I'm having a Books collections with the following schema:

```
Books
 - Title <string> [Stored, indexed]
 - Author <Multi-values string> [Stored, indexed]
 - ISBN <int> [Stored, indexed]
 - Content [indexed]
```

I want to add a new field to the schema called Tags (Multi-values string) that will be frequently change.
Tags will be used as a kind of ENUM (e.g. Best seller, Recommended etc.).
The problems is that I don't have the "Content" field stored (impossible due to sizing limitations).
Therefore, the document cannot be updated (there is no partial update in Solr).

I thought about creating a new collection. Suppose I have the next two collections:

```
Books
 - Title <string> [Stored, indexed]
 - Author <Multi-values string> [Stored, indexed]
 - ISBN <int> [Stored, indexed]
 - Content [indexed]

Tags
 - ISBN <int> [Stored, indexed]
 - Tags <Multi-values string> [Stored, indexed]
```

I can make a JOIN query using the ISBN field.
However, I still want to be able to query facets from both collections.
I there anyway I can achieve it?

Another option I had is to add Tags fields as a nested (child) document.
By this approach, whatever I want can succeed, but I'm afarid it will require a massive update flow.
It will be much easier for me to import the entier Tags collection with ETL operation.
The Books collection hardly changes and it will force me to load into memory a lot of segments that would not be required if the Tags data was in a separate collection.

Is there another approach I missed and can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any examples of facets you want to query from both collections? Making two queries, one for each collection, is probably the most straight forward answer.

Comment: can you try the solr streaming ...https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/stream-source-reference.html

Comment: @MatsLindh I wrote down a partial schema of course for simplicity.
I am currently performing my facets by "Author", "Year of publication" etc. I would like to add the Tags field there as well.
Suppose I want to search for the word "orange" in the "Content" field. Once I get 100 books that contain the word "orange" in them, I would like to search only from the Tags that are relevant to them, in addition to the existing facets I have (Author, Year etc.). Thanks.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti can you elaborate on this? Do you mean search or facet stream? Can I use two collection in the same query?

Comment: To make it in a single request streaming expressions will be necessary, but you can use a join for filtering - so you filter against your books collection and facet on the tags collection, as well as querying and faceting on your books collection.

Comment: can you try below rollup(
  sort(
    innerJoin(
        search(Books,q="Title:("Java")", fl="Title,Author,ISBN", rows=10, sort="ISBN asc"),
        search(Tags, q="*:*", fl="Tags,ISBN", rows=10, sort="ISBN asc"),
        on="ISBN=ISBN"
        ),
    by="ISBN asc"
    ),
  over="Tags",
  count(*)
 )